Привет, никак не могу прочитать отправленные данные с web app на aiogram 3x
код на js
 let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp
    let niga = 5
    document.getElementById('pays').addEventListener('click', function () { 
            tg.sendData(JSON.stringify({ 'niga': niga }));

            tg.close();
        });

    

код на питоне:
@dp.message(F.content_type == ContentType.WEB_APP_DATA)
async def web_app2(message: types.Message, dp: Dispatcher):
web_app_data = message.web_app_data
parsed_data = json.loads(web_app_data.data)

print(parsed_data)
await message.answer(parsed_data)

я не знаю как реализовать в aiogram 3x получение обработку данных в web app, помогите :<
